# Suggestion regarding user control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, listbox

I am working on an app named E-Diary in WPF. Now I have to implement the the real diary input, means when i write in a box then i go to the 2nd box and so on. It is like a real diary. As in  the image   [image]

Now I need suggestions regarding implementation of above given description that whether i use text boxes in the list box **or** I make a user control which contains text boxes and labels as in image and use it in the wpf according to the number of boxes.
I also have to save data in the database, If I use a button with each user control then how it could be managed to save the specific data?

This might be not a real question in terms of the FAQ rules of stackoverflow but I have been thinking for a long time but cant find the right way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF you don't have to make UserControls quite as often as in WinForms to get a good design.
And this is IMHO true for your problem too.

Go on and use a Listbox or ItemsControl but use DataTemplates to display and edit the dataitems just as you want to.
Here is a nice tuturial how to do this: [Data Templates](http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html) and make sure to have a look at the MSDN Documentation on [Data Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) too.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the `ItemsControl` since that is what I would do: `ItemsControl` with a `WrapPanel` as the `ItemsPanelTemplate`